# How do I turn off Magento system attribute short_description?

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.8

When I go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and and click on short_description, I edit the option 'values required' in the properties to "NO" from the drop-down, so it's not required.

Then I flush Cache and even re-index yet i can't seem to drag it out of my default "Attribute Set". It seems to still be locked with a little red icon in the corner. I can't seem to edit this. Can anyone help me understand how to trouble shoot this issue I'm having?

Comment: Do you want to remove "short_description" attribute from a particular attribute set?

Answer (score 5):

Turning off a system attribute has the risk that somewhere, something will get messed up. But if you want, you can do this easily by manipulating the database. Following can be done for any system attribute that has to be changed.

Now go to your database to `eav_attribute` table to the row with attribute_code `short_description`. In this row, set `is_user_defined` value from 0 to 1.

In Magento backend, go to `catalog -> attributes -> manage attribute sets` and select the set from which you want to remove `short_description`. Now you should be able to turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove the system attribute..
You can hide it by commenting the line 
or You can try this
[[http://www.richardcarterconsultancy.com/2013/11/how-to-disable-magento-short-description-field-for-products/][1]](http://www.richardcarterconsultancy.com/2013/11/how-to-disable-magento-short-description-field-for-products/%5d%5b1%5d)